# How to Insert StoredProc results into table, but specify a different date

Tags: sql, t-sql, getdate

I am executing a stored procedure, and I want to store the results into an existing table. The thing is, the table receiving the results needs to insert the current date at the same time.

The code below obviously won't work, but it's "kind of" what I'm trying to do?

```
    INSERT INTO [schema].[Table]
               ([column1]
               ,[column2]
               ,[column3]
               ,[column4]
               ,[DateColumn])
    VALUES(
        EXEC('schema.StoredProc'), 
        GETDATE()
    )
```

Answer (score 3):

Change the date column to have a default value:

```
alter table [schema].[Table] add constraint def_table_column default getdate() for datecolumn;
```

Then do the `insert`:

```
INSERT INTO [schema].[Table]([column1], [column2], [column3], [column4])
    EXEC 'schema.StoredProc' ;
```

Comment: I get the message: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'default'.

Comment: @blacksaibot the command for adding a default constraint is ALTER TABLE [schema].[tablename] ADD CONSTRAINT [name of constraint] DEFAULT getdate() FOR [columnname]

Comment: @Mattgb . . . Thank you very much.  Other databases allow `default` in that context.  I forget that not all do.

Answer (score 2):

For an alternative solution;
You can use table value function instead of procedures.

```
INSERT INTO  [schema].[Table]
               ([column1]
               ,[column2]
               ,[column3]
               ,[column4]
               ,[DateColumn])
SELECT *,GETDATE() FROM dbo.fn_YourFunction()
```

Comment: Nice. Thank you. Now I've ran into a new problem. My stored procedure (which executes an openquery against a linked DB2 server) is returning the query rather than the results of the query. The output window displays the text of my SP's query and gives the message "A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded."

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/162060/insert-openquery-results-into-an-existing-table

Answer (score 0):

Plerase try this one.

```
If Object_Id('tempdb.dbo.#Tmp_datatable') Is Not NULL
Begin
    Drop Table dbo.#Tmp_datatable
End

INSERT Tmp_datatable EXEC('schema.StoredProc')

INSERT INTO  [schema].[Table]
           ([column1]
           ,[column2]
           ,[column3]
           ,[column4]
           ,[DateColumn])
SELECT *,GETDATE() FROM Tmp_datatable
```

Also you can perform other operation on temp table.